# How to check for two conditions using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

```
<root>
    <risk>
        <Category>02</Category>
        <NCD>
            <CoverCode>B05</CoverCode>
            <CI>
                <CD>3</CD>
            </CI>
        </NCD>
    </risk>
</root>
```

I need to check 2 conditions to get the required payload from the above. I am using transformation as below to check the 2 conditions. I want to get the value of CD only when Category is 02 and CoverCode is B05.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
{
    soapenv#Envelope: {
        soapenv#Body: {

            component:{
                coverageClassCode:payload.root.risk.NCD.CI.CD when payload.root.risk.Category == '02' && payload.root.risk.NCD.CoverCode == 'B05' otherwise "" ,
                blockedDr:"N"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes, you should use `when-otherwise-when` or just two `when`s in a row.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: Add the code to your question

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Shouldn't it be `when payload.risk.root.Category`, not `when payload.root.Category`?

Comment: Yes, sorry corrected that but still it doesn't like &&.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `&&` to `and` -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
{
    soapenv#Envelope:{
        soapenv#body:{
            component:{
                coverageClassCode:payload.root.risk.NCD.CI.CD when payload.root.risk.Category == '02' and payload.root.risk.NCD.CoverCode == 'B05' otherwise "",
                //payload.root.risk.NCD.CI.CD when payload.root.risk.Category == '02' && payload.root.risk.NCD.CoverCode == 'B05' otherwise "" ,
                blockedDr:"N"
            }
        }
    }

}
```